# Compare 2 Columns and Delete non-matching

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM   probid_auction_media 
WHERE auction_id NOT IN SELECT DISTINCT auction_id FROM probid_auctions");
```

this is the code i am using, what i wish to do is to compare the column auction_id from probid_auction_media to the column auction_id from probid_auctions and delete any ones that do not math from probid_auction_media

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis:

```
DELETE FROM   probid_auction_media 
WHERE auction_id NOT IN 
      ( SELECT auction_id FROM probid_auctions )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parentheses. Also, a `DISTINCT` probably isn't necessary:

```
DELETE FROM probid_auction_media
    WHERE auction_id NOT IN (SELECT auction_id FROM probid_auction)
```